# Home flag in content languages is set to NO and cannot be set back to YES

Tags: joomla-3.x, language

I am trying to build a multilingual site with Joomla 3.9. Due to unknown reason, one of the "Home" flag in content languages is set to "NO" and I can't set it back to "YES". And the result is, it can't be seen or be selected in the homepage. But as I added it into system, it was all "YES" in this column and it worked.

Is there any way to set it back to "NO" (except changing it directly in database) or anyone knows what causes this problem? Thanks for any helps!

[image]

Comment: Solved. The homepage in Chinese was not set.

Comment: We prefer that you not "resolve" a question using a comment.  With the intent to educate and empower, please post an answer that details exactly what you did to resolve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.

The NO in Column Home in content languages means there is no Homepage set in the menu. After you switch to the mean and set a homepage, the value will turn to a YES. In my case I just go to the Chinese menu and set a menu item as homepage. After that the problem is solved.